# flash dynamic textfield, multiline and wordwrap acting funky

Tags: flash

I have this weird thing happening with flash and a dynamic textfield. Basically, someone rolls over a marker on a map, and a tooltip pops up with a dynamic textfield. The textfield is set to multiline=true and wordwrap = true, and I defined a specific width of 160 pixels.

The problem is, some of my text is jumping to the next line, some of it is just getting cut off. So if I have a line like "The Cat Jumped Over the Box",  On one line I will see "The Cat Jumped" and on the next line I would see "the Box". It looks like it is masking out the "over" line and not pushing it to the next line.

It's not doing this for everything, just some longer lines. This is a really weird bug and I have tried for 8 hours to get this fixed. Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

Comment: yeah that wasn't the problem. It was something with the text resizing with tweener that was messing it up and reusing a textfield movieclip instead of creating a dynamic textfield for each instance. But thank you for the response.